# MDX for getting dimensions of a cube?

Tags: mdx, cognos-tm1

Assume that a cube named `MyCube` has 2 dimensions, and I want to build an MDX `SELECT` statement without knowing the name of the dimensions but I have a list of elements with one element from each dimension:

```
SELECT [ELEM X from first dimension] ON 0,  [ELEM Y from second dimension] ON 1
FROM [MyCube]
```

Alternatively is there a function that will return the list of all dimensions and that I can use to built my MDX?

Comment: I don't know enough about MDX to answer this, but I think [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/75c3601c-81de-40b2-b5d3-5f0993a043e4/mdx-query-to-get-the-all-dimension-names-in-a-cube?forum=sqlanalysisservices) may be helpful.  Looks like you could maybe just select everything (`*`) and then filter to get just the dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can query a dimension without knowing its exact name. You don't even have to know the names of any member, as this example shows. Just be careful in case you are returned a grid of 10000 x 10000 results!

```
SELECT 
{Dimensions(0).Levels(0).members} ON ROWS, 
{Dimensions(1).Levels(0).members} ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Sales]
```

It may also be useful to use `.members(0)` or `[Measures].allMembers` to specify items where the name is not known.